# How can I quickly retrieve a value from a MapIterator returned from Object.keys function?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, ecmascript-6

I have a variable `RULE_TABLE` which is a map which maps an object to a string.

I want to retrieve some value from the keys of `RULE_TABLE` quickly in Chrome dev console.

If I run

```
a = RULE_TABLE.keys()
```

I get a MapIterator object.

[image]

However I try either of these:

- `a[0]`
- a.get(0)

I fail to retrieve any value:

[image]

Eventually I convert it into a list this way

```
var keys = [];
for (var key of RULE_TABLE.keys()) {
    keys.push(key);
}
```

My question is:

Is there a quicker way to convert a `MapIterator` into a list? Like how `list()` does it in python for example?

Chrome version: Version 57.0.2987.133 (64-bit)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming you are using native `Map`'s and it's ok to use ES6, you can use the [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator) to expand `Map.keys()`

```
const keys = [...RULE_TABLE.keys()]
```

Comment: It works on this version of chrome! Most of the existing answers on SO are not for est6. Thanks!